# Strange 'where 1970 and' clause in MySql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I am reviewing some old PHP code where MySql statements are hard-coded. I found a statement with a strange `where` clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 1970
    AND Sale_Price.Server__ = `Server`.Server__
    ...
```

What is the purpose of this `1970` number in the `where` clause? I have never seen this before. Is there a specific purpose?

It looks like an harmless typo/bug to me which I could remove. Do you agree?

**UPDATE**

Here is more information about the joins:

```
SELECT ...
FROM `Server`, Product_Ref
    LEFT JOIN Sale_Price ON Product_Ref.Product_Ref__ = Sale_Price.Product_Ref__
    LEFT JOIN Purchase_Price ON Product_Ref.Product_Ref__ = Purchase_Price.Product_Ref__
    LEFT JOIN Product_Category ON Product_Ref.Product__ = Product_Category.Product__
    WHERE 1970
        AND Sale_Price.Server__ = `Server`.Server__
        AND Sale_Price.Date_Enter < NOW()
        AND Sale_Price.Server__ IN ($this->salesServerIds)
```

Comment: I've seen similar things used (I think `1 = 1`) where the `AND` portions are dynamically generated as it simplifies the programming with no need to check if `AND` needs to be added to the start of the statement. Not sure if it's the same here.

Comment: could be a way to get all entries, this is similar with WHERE true

Comment: Used similarly like I use `WHERE 1=1`

Comment: true means 1 but not 1970. Am i right? Can we use any number rather than 1 for true condition?

Comment: any number evaluates to true, except 0

Comment: So if I use if($var == true )  and if($var == 1970) both are equal ?

Comment: No, `if(true)` and `if(1970)` are equal

Comment: ok Thank you :) SO is really a knowledge hub.

Comment: Sounds like a hidden Join using a where condition. Do you have conditions that point to several tables?

Comment: Might be there is dynamic where clause that might be added if value exists within variable else user have used `1970` instead of `1` somewhat like as `where 1`

Comment: @Elzo I have included more information about the joins in my question.

Comment: As you have proper joins my theory is not valid. If you have version control (git,svn,cvs) you can check when it was added and if is a typo or a copy paste error, which I suspect. The effect of having it there is that you will get all results. You will get for example even entries where Sale_Price.Date_Enter is in the future. Make a test and confirm

Comment: So others explained what it does and I just wanted to point out that whoever wrote this `1970` thing shall be punished not for doing so, as it's perfectly fine, but for not making code clear by just using `1` (or `1 = 1`).

Comment: @Elzo If you create an answer, I'll approve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities as we discussed in comments:

A *hidden* true condition:

```
 ... WHERE 1 = 1;
 ... WHERE 1;
 ... WHERE 1970;

 -- All numbers except 0 evaluate to TRUE and will return all entries.
```

The second option is an *error*. If you have version control (git,svn,cvs) you can check when it was added and if is a typo or a copy paste error, which I suspect. The effect of having it there is that you will get all results; you will get for example even entries where *Sale_Price.Date_Enter* is in the future.